# Keycloak group-based policy to prevent user from accessing a client

Tags: keycloak

I just started using keycloak for my spring project. I have been trying to make a multi-tenant approach using group-based policy but unsuccessful. The user is still able to access a client that are not in the allowed groups of group-based policy.

> - User1 (group1)
> - User2 (group2)
> - Client1 = accessible by group1
> - Client2 = accessible by group2

`User2` shouldn't be able to access `Client1`.

Here's how I did it.

- Created a group-based policy in `Client1`.

[image: group1 policy]

- Created a new permission in `Client1` with `group1 only policy`.
  [image: permission with group1 policy]

With this setup I shouldn't be able to access the `Client1` with `User2` user.

Answer (score 0):

Do not misuse groups as tenants, use realms as tenants.